# PHP Increment number, each time a new div is created

Tags: php, mysql, html, increment, ranking

Basically I have a PHP script that creates a div for each item in the database, but I want to have a "rank" number in each div created, i.e:

```
-----------------
Rank: 1      < div 1
-----------------
Rank: 2      < div 2
-----------------
Rank: 3      < div 3
-----------------
```

And so on..

Here's my current code...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $name = stripslashes($row['name']);
    $description = stripslashes($row['description']);
    $votes = stripslashes($row['votes']);
    $id = ($row['id']);
    $link = ($row['link']);
    $rank = 0;
    ?>

    <div class="site" id="site">
    <u><center>
    <strong><a href="<?php echo $link ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $name; ?></a></strong></u>
    </font></center>
    <p>Rank:<?php echo $rank++ ; ?></p>
    <p><b><?php echo $description; ?></b><br />
    Votes:<b> <?php echo $votes; ?></b><br />
    </p>
    </div>

   <center>
    <?php
}
?>
```

But that doesn't work, any help would be greatly appreciated. (Also, the div's continue over multiple pages).

Comment: You are setting $rank to 0 every time you loop. Plus, you might have to do $rank++ outside of the echo-- I am not sure if $rank++ actually returns the new number or not (but don't quote me on that)

Comment: No need to put it outside the echo, but indeed the initialization should happen outside the loop. An FYI: `$var++` returns the pre-incremented value, `++$var` the post-incremented one.

Comment: So then echoing $rank++ would echo 0 every time it loops

Comment: also you have an orphan closing </font> tag

Comment: Okay, that worked, but now I have this problem, when the user goes to the next page, it starts from one again (Click next at bottom: http://aviatex14.co.uk/webmash/top.php )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `$rank = 0;` outside of the loop. Otherwise it will be always 0.

Answer (score 1):

You define the `$rank`-variable in your loop, so in every loop-round it's defined with the value `0`. Define the counter-variable outside the loop and increase it in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Rank need to be outside the loop or you will reset it to 0 everytime

```
$rank = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $name = stripslashes($row['name']);
    $description = stripslashes($row['description']);
    $votes = stripslashes($row['votes']);
    $id = ($row['id']);
    $link = ($row['link']);
    ?>

    <div class="site" id="site">
    <u><center>
    <strong><a href="<?php echo $link ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $name; ?></a></strong></u>
    </font></center>
    <p>Rank:<?php echo $rank ; ?></p>
    <p><b><?php echo $description; ?></b><br />
    Votes:<b> <?php echo $votes; ?></b><br />
    </p>
    </div>

   <center>
    <?php
     $rank++;
}
?>
```

**Additional for comment:**

Use an offset for that, for example

```
$result_per_page = 5; // this is the number of result you show per page
$offset = isset($_GET['id'])? (int)$_GET['id'] : 1;
$rank = $offset * $result_per_page;
```

Comment: Thanks, worked a charm, but now I have this problem.... http://aviatex14.co.uk/webmash/top.php (Click next and watch what happens to the rank)

Comment: i added an update to my answer. this wil help you offset for each page

Comment: Sorry if I'm becoming a pain, but I don't know where to use that code, because I *think* it contradicts some other code, here's the php for the whole thing (The contradictory bit is just below the the SQL connect) http://pastebin.com/5Q62Zv1N

Comment: just replace it like this then: `$rank = ($page-1) * $site_number` you already have the rest of the code :) no pain!

Answer (score 1):

`$rank` needs to be defined outside of the `while` statement. Every time it loops it's resetting to zero. Also, increment `$rank` elsewhere - it makes the code slightly more robust and intelligible.